# Merge two datasets based on certain conditions, while maintaining specific columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

**Objective**

I have two datasets, df1 and df2. I would like to merge the two, only when their datetime values match within 20 seconds of each other. I would also like to keep the Duration column within the df2 column

```
  df1 

  End                           Duration

  1/22/2020 5:42:13 AM          34
  1/30/2020 12:12:50 AM          5


  df2

  Sent

  1/22/2020 5:42:20 AM
  1/31/2020 12:00:00 PM
```

**Desired output:**

```
  End                                 Sent                       Duration


  1/22/2020 5:42:13 AM               1/22/2020 5:42:20 AM        34
```

**Dput:**

```
 df1


 structure(list(End = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1/22/2020 5:42:13 AM", 
 "1/30/2020 12:12:50 AM"), class = "factor"), Duration = c(34L, 
 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))


df2

structure(list(Sent = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1/22/2020 5:42:20 AM", 
"1/31/2020 12:00:00 PM"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

**What I have tried**

```
df3<-crossing(endtime = as.POSIXct(df1$End,format ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" ), 
SentTime = as.POSIXct(df2$Sent, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")) %>% 
filter((endtime - seconds(20)) <= SentTime, 
      (endtime + seconds(20)) >= (SentTime)) %>%
mutate_all(format, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") %>%
distinct(SentTime, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

The above code matches the datetimes within 20 seconds well, however, the corresponding duration column is not there. How can I match these datasets if they are within 20 seconds of each other, while also maintaining the corresponding Duration column?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create all possible combination with `crossing`, change columns to `POSIXct` format and select only the rows where the difference between `End` and `Sent` is less than 20 seconds.

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::crossing(df1, df2) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(End, Sent), lubridate::mdy_hms) %>%
  filter(abs(as.numeric(difftime(End, Sent, "seconds"))) < 20)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  End                 Duration Sent               
#  <dttm>                 <int> <dttm>             
#1 2020-01-22 05:42:13       34 2020-01-22 05:42:20
```

Comment: Thank you @ronak I will try. how do I keep the outcome Distinct? For instance, keeping the df2 or the df1 value distinct?

Comment: Do you have duplicate rows in the output? You can add `%>% distinct()` at the end to get unique rows.

Comment: Ok @ronak I will try. Also, how did you retain the Duration column, when it’s not specified in the code? Thank you

Comment: When we use `crossing` `Duration` is already present as column and it remains till the end since `filter` removes only rows and not columns.

Comment: Ok let me try this